# Where does "otay" come from?

Tags: etymology, vocabulary

I've heard a few people (all native English speakers) recently use "otay" in place of "okay", both in writing and when speaking. Where does that word come from? For that matter, is it a word at all?

I'm guessing it means the same thing as "okay", but are there any nuances in its usages that I'm missing?

Comment: I deleted my comments. It does seem to be 'catchphrase' usage from children's tv. I still think it's basically 'childish speech' but something has to popularise it, I guess.

Comment: Fun fact: [k] and [t] are allophones in Hawaiian. Additional fun fact: the previous fun fact has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When *I* use it, I'm deliberately emulating baby talk. It doesn't really mean anything different than "okay" (pronounced properly); it's just a way to be, I dunno, cutesy.

I didn't know about the Little Rascals/Buckwheat connection, possibly because I grew up without a TV. I'm sure Buckwheat contributed to at least some of the popularity of "otay", and possibly I absorbed it from someone who (unbeknownst to me) was imitating the TV show, but it's also possible that this is something that each generation/school/user invents anew.

Comment: This one's good enough for me. It sounds 'reinventable' on demand once you take on board the baby-talk aspect, so like you I attach little importance to kids' programs that may help to promote the usage (in reality they probably simply reflect it, for most purposes).

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure that you absorbed it from someone imitating the TV show ;)

Answer (score 12):

"Otay" comes from [The Little Rascals (a.k.a. "Our Gang")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Little_Rascals), a 1920's comedy series featuring a variety of child actors, in particular one called Buckwheat, who had a bit of a lisp or perhaps a minor speaking impediment at the time.  This character was later caricatured by Eddie Murphy on Saturday Night Live, who made a big production out of the practically unintelligible "Buckwheat dialect", including "Oh-Tay!" specifically as a catchphrase.

Comment: Can't agree, for same reasons given against @Callithumpian offering in the same vein. These relate to childish usage, they're not neologisms.

Comment: +1: Murphy's Buckwheat character is the more probable source of the current (and recent) vogue usage. The *Buckwheat Tangs* ("Buckwheat Sings") album ad bit was probably longer than the original Buckwheat's entire cumulative screen time over the course of the series, and I don't remember going a whole day without hearing at least one "O-tay!" for a couple of years there.

Comment: +1 for Eddie Murphy's role. (Corrected his last name in your answer).

Answer (score 6):

I believe it comes from the character of [Buckwheat](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOLWWLYY1a8) in the old TV show *The Little Rascals*.

[image: otay image]

Comment: I'd be very surprised if that were the actual origin. Probably just a reflection of the fact that a child (perhaps by implication a not-particularly-well-spoken one) may well make this mispronunciation.

Comment: @Fumble: For what it's worth, this is the #1 definition at [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Otay%20) as well.

Comment: Well, yes. But it's simply because Buckwheat is a little kiddie who talks childishly 'cute' and inaccurately. I doubt *Otay* was really a 'neologism' in any of these usages - most of us have heard little kids get these plosives wrong in the early stages of talking.

Comment: @FF, likely not the origin, no, but I would not be surprised if it was the primary reason why it became popular 50 years ago or so and remains relatively so today.

Answer (score 1):

It absolutely originated from Buckwheat and his lisp. My entire generation grew up imitating it. I asked my 22 year old and her generation uses it from Eddie Murphy's reincarnation of Buckwheat in a movie, on record, and a reoccurring role of the character on Saturday Night Live. Then moving ahead to my 11-year-old son's generation, he sees it on Facebook, also in depictions of Buckwheat and he and his friends use it in imitating the Little Rascals.